# How to align items in a <h:panelGrid> to the right

Tags: css, jsf

How would I align everything in my  below to the far right?

```
<div id="container">    
     <h:form id="authenticate">
        <h:panelGrid columns="5" cellpadding="6">
             <h:inputText id="email" value="" />
             <p:watermark for="email" value="Email"/>
             <h:inputSecret id="password" value="" />
             <p:watermark for="password" value="Password"/>
             <p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" align="right"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
     </h:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`<h:panelGrid>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/panelGrid.html) renders a HTML table. You basically want to apply `text-align: right;` on every `<td>` element it renders. With the current code, easiest would be to apply the following:

```
#authenticate table td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

---

You can of course also be more specific, e.g. giving the `<h:panelGrid>` its own `styleClass` and defining a rule in CSS (which would be applied directly on the rendered HTML `<table>` element).

```
<h:panelGrid styleClass="className">
```

with

```
.className td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

---

You can also give each `<td>` element its own class by `columnClasses` attribute which accepts a commaseparated string of CSS classnames which are to be applied repeatedly on the `<td>` elements. If you want to apply the same class on every `<td>` element, just specify it once:

```
<h:panelGrid columnClasses="className">
```

with

```
.className {
    text-align: right;
}
```

---

As an extra hint: rightclick the webpage in webbrowser and choose *View Source*, then you'll understand better what JSF is all exactly generating.

Comment: Note:  For columnClasses they apply to the _rendered_ columns, not all the columns listed.  For Mojarra 2.0 this is the _only_ way to set any attribute on the generated td-element.

Comment: You often enhance 'old' posts to be more generic, easier to find etc. Is this one eligable as well?, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136972/how-to-specify-styles-for-hpanelgrid-in-jsf

Answer (score 5):

actually in same form i used `<p:panel>` and got good result. looks like ;

```
<p:panel  styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <p:commandButton value="Add New Tab"
            actionListener="#{xxx.createNewTab}" process="@this"
            update="tabView" style="float:right !important;margin:0px 0px 3px 0px;" />
            </p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but might help someone, as it was what I needed...

If the alignment is not limited to this specific table, but rather the default format for all table cells, then just add this to your CSS file:

```
td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then, all `<td>` elements, including those generated by JSF, will be formatted that way.