# Aligning content inside panelGrid columns

Tags: jsf, richfaces, primefaces

How do I align the content in the columns created by panelGrid component to the `top` ?

I tried with no success, the following code

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="vertical-align:top;  " >
       <p:tabView style="margin:0px 0px 50px 0px; width: 450px; padding-top: 0px;vertical-align:top" ></p:tabView>                
       <p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true" style="width: 300px; vertical-align:top" ></p:menubar>
</h:panelGrid>
```

But the 2 columns created hereby still remain vertically middle aligned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right%20this) answer, you can do like this (I like this approach the most)

```
<h:panelGrid columnClasses="className">

.className {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: you'll need a column class for each column <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="className, className, className" >

Answer (score 16):

for me it works if you do it like that:

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="6" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4" styleClass="panelColumns">
</h:panelGrid>
```

and create a css file which contains:

```css
.panelColumns td {
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

just as additional hint .. so you do not have to search to long :)