# How apply CSS on a <h:inputText>?

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to apply CSS to my `<h:inputText>` but without success so far :

```html
<h:form id="contactform">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="name">Name</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}" >
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameMessage"></f:ajax>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="nameMessage" for="name" />

    <h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{contact.sendMessage}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
</h:form>
```

My CSS:

```css
#contactform .text-input{
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:solid 10px #000000;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:178px;
    padding:8px 5px;
    color:#797979;
}
```

If i try to apply this CSS style in some HTML input field it works, but not in JSF 2.0.

**EDIT:**

Update this part of my code in JSF:

```
<h:inputText id="name" styleClass="text-input" value="#{contact.client.name}"  >
```

Insert this code in my CSS file:

```
text-input{
    border:solid 1px #e0e0e0;
}
```

But it seems the same thing, nothing change.

Output:

```
<form id="j_idt35" name="j_idt35" method="post" action="/brainset/contact.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt35" value="j_idt35" /> 
<table class="contactform"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td><label for="j_idt35:name"> Name</label></td> 
            <td><input id="j_idt35:name" type="text" name="j_idt35:name" class="text-input" onblur="mojarra.ab(this,event,'blur',0,'j_idt35:nameMessage')" /></td> 
            <td><span id="j_idt35:nameMessage"></span></td> 
        </tr> 
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

There is something weird here.
Update my code with the help of you guys:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="contactform" styleClass="contactform" columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="name">Nome</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}"  >
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameMessage"></f:ajax>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="nameMessage" for="name" />
    </h:panelGrid
</h:form>
```

so my CSS style is now this way:

```
.contactform .text-input{
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:solid 50px #000000;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:178px;
    padding:8px 5px;
    color:#797979;
}
```

if i apply the css style in a specific input-text it works, but it shouldn't apply to all input-text below in my table ?

Any idea?

Comment: What does the output look like. Is there an element matching the selector `#contactform .text-input`?

Comment: this question is related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right

Comment: Note that the `<table>` has a `class` attribute, but not an `id`. The selector should then be `.contactform .text-input` not `#contactform .text-input` The form doesn't contain an `id` attribute either.

Comment: the id form my form, can be something related to the css classes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output `<h:inputText ...>` should not have any `class` attribute by default. You can add a the `class` attribute by defining a `styleClass` attribute in the JSF tag

```
<h:inputText id="name" styleClass="text-input" value="#{contact.client.name}" >
</h:inputText>
```

See the [reference](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html) for details

Answer (score 2):

The CSS class selector start with `.`, you should try the following:

```css
.text-input{
   border:solid 1px #e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Psy, it works.
but i have to do this for all <h:inputText> ?

Comment: @Valter Every component that requires that style will need the `styleClass="text-input"` attribute.

Comment: Okay, now i get it.
Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html). There is an attribute `styleClass` which can be set

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's more appropriate to use h:outputLabel.  I've not had problems applying css to h:outputLabel, but have had similar css application woes as you using h:outputText.