# How to align <h:panelGrid> itself NOT items in a center?

Tags: html, css, jsf

When i use this snippet code

```
<h:panelGrid id="myGrid" columns="1"
rendered="#{myBean.showResults}" width="50%"
border="1" style="text-align: center;">
```

The items of the panelGrid  will be centralized
BUT
I want to centralize h:panelGrid itself in the center of the my XHTML page
Like this HTML code

```
<table id="myGrid" border="1" align="center">
```

Comment: CAn we see the rendered HTML output? Not everyone knows what a `<h:panelGrid>` will output ;)

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/q/3714143/617373

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided that it has a known width, give it a left and right margin of `auto`. This way it will center itself relative to the parent block element.

```
<h:panelGrid ... style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

#### See also:

- [Center a div in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281087/center-a-div-in-css/2281107#2281107)

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a panelgrid that has the size of your page and set the style of the parent grid to text-align center. Then your child grid will be centered on page (remove the text-align: center style from your child panelgrid