# Apply styleClass to parent panelGrid element and not to children

Tags: css, jsf

I'm trying to apply a `styleClass` to a `h:panelGrid` without applying it to its children:

```
<h:panelGrid id="mainPanelGrid" columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="topAligned" >
    <p:fieldset id="fs1" legend="fs1" style="width: max-content">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="id1" value="#{messages.label_application}" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="id1" required="true" value="som">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messages.label_select}" noSelectionOption="true" />  
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="id1" />
        </h:panelGrid>             
    </p:fieldset>  

     <p:fieldset id="fs2" legend="fs2" style="width: max-content">  
         <h:panelGrid columns="3">
             <!--more fields-->     
         </h:panelGrid>  
     </p:fieldset>
</h:panelGrid>
```

My topAligned css:

```
.topAligned td{
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

The problem is that I need to top align the two fieldset and that works well with the `styleClass` I apply, but it also applies this `styleClass` to all the children.  Therefore, all the fields (`outputLabel`, `selectOneMenu`, etc...) of the two fieldset get top aligned too...

I tried all the different ways to specify the top alignment from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right) but without success...  I also tried to look at the html source but it gets a bit confusing with all the jsf and primefaces stuff...

If you know a trick that will work...

Comment: you can always remove the `!important` and overwrite children, or use a css `:not` selector in a clever way. It all depends on your generated DOM. Try uploading your output without PF gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
.topAligned td{
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

and the JSF-generated HTML output

```
<table class="topAligned">
    ...
</table>
```

you're basically applying the style on *every single* `<td>` element of the `<table>`, also those of the nested `<table>`s.

If you want to apply the style on only the immediate `<td>` elements of the parent `<table>`, then you should be using `columnClasses` attribute instead:

```
<h:panelGrid ... columnClasses="topAligned,topAligned">
```

with

```
.topAligned {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will end up in the generated HTML output as follows:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="topAligned">...</td>
            <td class="topAligned">...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and not be applied on the `<td>`s of the nested `<table>`s.

Note that I also removed the nonsensicial `!important` workaround. It's supposed to be used only when you want to override a hardcoded `style` by an external CSS style.

Also note that this problem is not specifically related to JSF. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You'd have had exactly the same problem when dealing with "plain vanilla" HTML/CSS. The problem is more in the lack of familiarity with basic HTML and CSS. On http://htmldog.com you can find decent HTML/CSS tutorials.

Comment: +1. Brilliant, as always.  However your solution is with `columnClasses="topAligned,topAligned"` JSF specific. Imagine what would CSS folk say if they saw a peace of JSF code.

Comment: I was hoping you would show up and boom ! Works great, many thanks.  I had not understood the `columnClasses` attribute well (especially the part where you have to specify for EACH column the style to apply)...  You're right I lack basic CSS but could not find what I wanted in tutos...