# How to specify styles for h:panelgrid in jsf

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I using a simple `h:panelGrid` for displaying the table how could i specify styles for the table to make it better. i am a bit confused with all the stuff i looked online
This is what the code that i have been using

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2"  cellpadding="10"
            cellspacing="1" style="align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Registration" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="User Name:" escape="false" />
        <h:inputText value="Hello World" />
            <h:outputText value="Password:" escape="false" />
            <h:inputSecret value="" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Could you please specify the list of opssible optons for specifying the css or inline styles for elements in jsf 
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align items in a <h:panelGrid> to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right)

Comment: Please undo the edit of your question. It changes it to much. Create a new question, but better yet, use google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to use inline styles. Since jsf is a html code generator in this regard, inline styles ofthen do not apply to the html element you want them applied to. Use the `styleClass` attribute,and create css with the right selectors for the html elements you want to style. Use the apllied class in those selectors

**See also**

- [How to align items in a <h:panelGrid> to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right)

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje can you suggest me some references for using external stylesheets in jsf

Comment: What is 'external'? You can use the html way and the <h:outputStylesheet .../> way