# Right alignment for one row

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have JSF table with left alignment for all rows. But I would like to apply right alignment on one row. I tried this:

```
 <h:panelGroup styleClass="table-right">
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.method}"> </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
 </h:panelGroup>

.table-right {
    text-align: rigth;
}
```

But it's not working. What is the proper way to apply CSS class for one h:panelGroup and align it's content on the right side?

Comment: You spelled right wrong. is this in the code or is this in the post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align items in a <h:panelGrid> to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714143/how-to-align-items-in-a-hpanelgrid-to-the-right)

Comment: I have h:panelGroup not h:panelGrid

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the html, you'll see the `h:panelGroup` is rendered as a `<span>`.

The span-tag is an inline-element, meaning it will be as small as possible and you can't set a width on it. You can verify this, if you add i.e. `border: 1px solid black;` to the styleClass. It has no effect to either left- or right-align something in a container, that is just big enough.

I think you can solve it by making the `panelGroup` a `block`/`inline-block` element and putting a width on it:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```